# How to setup a node js server that connects a mysql db in cpanel

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am a total newbie trying to fire up a node js server in cpanel that simply connects to a mysql db, nonetheless when I include the mysql bits they get completely ignored, no errors or reference to mysql at all. Any ideas?

```
const http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'admin',
   password : 'password',
   database : 'members',
   port:3306
});
// Create an instance of the http server to handle HTTP requests
let app = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    // Set a response type of plain text for the response
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    // Send back a response and end the connection
    res.end('Hello World!\n');   
    con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.end('Connected!');
    }); 

});

// Start the server on port 3000
app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Node server running on port 3000');
```

Answer (score 1):

You said you are connecting via cpanel. You need to put the hostname your server is providing you.

On your CPanel dashboard,

1. Go to phpMyAdmin
2. [Click the Variables tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8A1j.png)
3. Filter for the variable "hostname"
4. Copy the Value. My server is hostgator so i have mine as "*****.hostgator.com"

Use this connection instead:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host     : '*****.hostgator.com',
user     : 'admin',
password : 'password',
database : 'members',
});
```

*You don't need to put the port.

Then, you need to whitelist your IP Address.

1. On your CPanel Dashboard, click on "Remote MySQL".
2. Go to whatsmyip to know your computer's IP Address.
3. Add your computer's IP Address to "Remote MySQL"

That's it. Your MySQL connection should work now.

Comment: Can an analogous procedure be made for a Postgres database?

Answer (score 0):

You have created a server and you are making the connection on an HTTP API request and this is the reason you are not able to see anything on the command line. Try hitting localhost:3000 on the postman and you will be able to see the connection. There is one more correction you have to avoid sending a response before getting connected to the database.

```
const http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'admin',
password : 'password',
database : 'members',
port:3306
});
// Create an instance of the http server to handle HTTP requests
let app = http.createServer((req, res) => {
// Set a response type of plain text for the response
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

// Send back a response and end the connection
//res.end('Hello World!\n'); // comment this line   
con.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
res.end('Connected!');
}); 

});

// Start the server on port 3000
app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Node server running on port 3000');
```

Hope this helps! Please let me know!

Comment: if you don't have postman then you can hit localhost:3000 at chrome or any other browser which you have.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `db_config.js` file:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const dbConfig = {
    host: 'your host name have in variables > hostname',
    user: 'userName',
    password: 'user password',
    database: 'db name',
};

const pool = mysql.createPool(dbConfig);

module.exports = pool;
```

And import pool where you want in your controller like this:

```js
const pool = require('../db');

pool.query(checkEmailQuery, [emailToFind], (err, results) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Database query error: ", err);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: "Database query error", error: err.message });
  }
  
  if (results.length > 0) {
    // Email exists, delete the row
    const deleteQuery = `DELETE FROM users_data WHERE Email = ?`;
    pool.query(deleteQuery, [emailToFind], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Failed to delete data from database: ", err);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to delete data from database", error: err.message });
      }
      console.log("Data deleted successfully", result);
      res.json({ message: "Data associated with the email has been deleted successfully" });
    });
  } else {
    console.log("No matching email found to delete.");
    res.json({ message: "No matching email found, no data deleted." });
  }
});
```